# How read image from path stored in Mysql table

Tags: mysql, r

I have some JPEG images, their ID and their path have been stored in MySQL table 
called `image_table` which contains 2 columns `(ID, path_image)`.

Now, I want to read  image using its path stored in my database, 
Please help me to solve my problem.

```
library(jpeg)
library(RODBC)
channel <- odbcConnect("mysql 3", uid="titi") 
result  <-   paste("select * from image_table")
sqlQuery(channel, result,error=TRUE)
```

The result of sqlquery is on r editor:

```
> sqlQuery(channel, result,error=TRUE)
   ID    path
  1 F:Rdjelfa1.jpg
  2 F:Rdjelfa2.jpg
  3 F:Rdjelfa3.jpg
  4 F:Rdjelfa4.jpg
  5 F:Rdjelfa5.jpg
  6 F:Rdjelfa6.jpg
  7 F:Rdjelfa7.jpg
```

> 

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to read an image from its path which is stored in Mysql using R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24511379/how-to-read-an-image-from-its-path-which-is-stored-in-mysql-using-r)

Comment: I have delet the first one.

Comment: Please add the results of your final `sqlQuery` to your question.  Your question doesn't seem to be about `MySql` but about linking to remote paths.  We need to see what your remote paths look like to be able to help.

Comment: The result of sqlquery is on r editor seems like this:
> sqlQuery(channel, result,error=TRUE)
  ID           path
1  1 F:Rdjelfa1.jpg
2  2 F:Rdjelfa2.jpg
3  3 F:Rdjelfa3.jpg
4  4 F:Rdjelfa4.jpg
5  5 F:Rdjelfa5.jpg
6  6 F:Rdjelfa6.jpg
7  7 F:Rdjelfa7.jpg
>